# Read/Open Oceancolor data from MODIS with nc format

Tags: r

This month the oceancolor data format (http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cms/) have began change from hdf into nc. I work with R-software, but i can't open this kind of data using R..anyone have any idea?

```
> library (ncdf)

> indeso.nc <- open.ncdf('D:/A2015199.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc')
  Error in R_nc_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format
  Error in open.ncdf("D:/A2015199.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc") : 
  Error in open.ncdf trying to open file D:/A2015199.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc

> print (indeso.nc);
  Error in print(indeso.nc) : object 'indeso.nc' not found
```

More i read some new R-package (ncdf4 - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/index.html). But this package can't instaled

```
> library (ncdf4)
  Error in library(ncdf4) : there is no package called ‘ncdf4’

> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
  --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
  Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ncdf4’
  These will not be installed
```

Comment: Please read the documentation. And search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+read+netcdf

Comment: for another nc file is OK, but for oeancolor (http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cms/) data is not working.

Comment: But when i used SEADAS (http://seadas.gsfc.nasa.gov/) software it's work fine

Comment: `ncdf` package is now deprecated. You should use package `ncdf4`: http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/

Comment: Maybe it's ncdf 4.0 format, which is not supported by the ncdf package. Can you provide a link to the nc file so we can actually reproduce the problem?

Comment: i already tried to work with ncdf4, but i can't installed it into my R..you could see my question above..here the data [link] (http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2015199.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc
http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2015200.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc
http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2015201.L3m_DAY_SST_sst_4km.nc)

Comment: @RicardoOliveros-Ramos The file is opened with `ncdf4`, not `ncdf`.

Comment: @EkoSusilo See the link in my comment. By default, there is no `ncdf4` Windows binary available on CRAN

Comment: I'm assuming you're on Windows. You need RTools to compile, or download a binary from http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/

Comment: @RicardoOliveros-Ramos Yes, it is the link I already provided.

Comment: @Pascal thanks, you are right