# Reprojection oceancolor data in raster?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, map-projections, reprojection-error

regarding my previous question [Read/Open Oceancolor data from MODIS with nc format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553693/read-open-oceancolor-data-from-modis-with-nc-format). I have tried to read the ncdf oceancolor data [download here](http://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2014325053500.L2_LAC_SST.nc) using `ncdf4 package` with this code

```
library(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open('A2014325053500.L2_LAC_SST.nc')

# Get data for each variabel name as a large matrix
sst <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'geophysical_data/sst')
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'navigation_data/longitude')
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'navigation_data/latitude')
```

than this data, I convert to raster. But I failed to reproject the raster `figure 1`. The image should be like `figure 2`

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

r <- raster(sst,
        xmn=min(lat), xmx=max(lat), 
        ymn=min(lon), ymx=max(lon),
        crs=CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'))

proj='+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'
r2 <- projectRaster(r, crs=proj, method = 'ngb')
plot(r2)
```

Based on jbaums first suggestion the result is not correctly reprojected `figure 3`

I just realize that there is something wrong with the result when I increase the resolution. In the western and eastern part become white (no data). I used this code below:

```
r <- rasterize(df, raster(extent(df), res=0.0103011), 'sst', fun=mean)
```

Figure 1
[image: figure 1]

Figure 2
[image: figure 2]

Figure 3
[image: Figure 3]

Figure 4
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: You have passed the latitudinal and longitudinal limits with the wrong arguments. Latitude is `y`, not `x`.

Comment: It's hard to test since you don't provide data, but you're also providing the same source and target CRS...

Comment: @jbaums, the data link already posted in my question, see download here in my first sentence

Comment: Sorry.. Not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their current projection, the coordinates don't fall on a regular grid.

One way around this is to represent the coordinates as a `SpatialPoints` object, and then, if you need a raster, `rasterize` it.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

# Read in the data
nc <- nc_open('~/../Downloads/A2014325053500.L2_LAC_SST.nc')
sst <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'geophysical_data/sst')
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'navigation_data/longitude')
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'navigation_data/latitude')
nc_close(nc)

# Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame
p <- data.frame(lon=c(lon), lat=c(lat), sst=c(sst))
coordinates(p) <- ~lon+lat
proj4string(p) <- '+init=epsg:4326'

# Rasterize with appropriate resolution and aggregation function
r <- rasterize(p, raster(extent(p) * 1.04, res=0.05), 'sst', fun=mean)
# for high resolution look at ?gdalUtils::gdal_rasterize for efficiency
```

Here's a plot:

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r, at=seq(-75, 75, length=100), margin=FALSE, par.settings=BuRdTheme,
              colorkey=list(height=0.6), main='MODIS Sea Surface Temperature')
```

[image]

Comment: @ jbaums, I just realize that there is something wrong with the result when I increase the resolution. In the western and eastern part become white (no data). I used this code below:`r <- rasterize(df, raster(extent(df), res=0.0103011), 'sst', fun=mean)`. Regarding my case, could you give sample how to use `gdal_rasterize`

Comment: Please see my last figure (Fig 4)

Comment: @EkoSusilo the points are not dense enough in those areas, and so there are raster cells that contain no points.

Comment: Do you have suggestions?

Comment: @EkoSusilo If you want to create data where there are none, you can start coarser and then resample (`raster::resample` or `gdalUtils::gdalwarp`). See the resampling options. Otherwise look into, e.g., kriging.